# Verification of Transfer

Tags: transaction-verification

Ok I have made bit Cash paper wallet ... Now I am going to transfer to it from my Trezor..  my question is how do I verify that what I transfered is on the paper wallet?

Thanks  Linda

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Blockchain Explorer](https://blockchain.info/) and just search for your address either the source address from the Trezor HW Wallet or the destination one, the paper wallet's address.
You will be able to view the whole transaction and the balance in both addresses.
Note that transactions take some time to be included in a block 10-20 minutes, the bigger your transaction fee the faster your transaction will be included in a block.

Comment: @LindaMerrick You are welcome. If my response solves your question you can check it as the correct one. So that the question is answered and not showing as unanswered.